# Rotating circle at a particular centre

Tags: iphone, ios, cabasicanimation

I have created a circle using CAShapeLayer. I want to rotate this circle at fix centre. i'm using following code for animation. Using this code circle is rotating but not at a fix centre. Is centre keeps on changing. I don't want that to happen.

This is my code for animation

```
CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0 * rotations * 2.0 ];
    rotationAnimation.duration = 10.0; //    rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 1.0; 
    rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];

    [circle1 addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
```

Thanks

Comment: [circle1 setAnchorPoint:(0.5,0.5)]; that will keep it inside rect.

Answer (score 0):

This will keep it inside rect.

```
[circle1 setAnchorPoint:(0.5,0.5)]; 

CGFloat angle = rotationAnimation.toValue;
CGFloat radius = someRadius;
CGPoint rotationCenter = CGPointMake(centerX,centerY); 
circle1.frame = CGRectMake(rotationCenter.x + radius * cos(angle),  rotationCenter.y + radius * sin(angle), circle1.frame.size.width, circle1.frame.size.height);
```